# Calculate cart by localstorage with SSR in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js, local-storage, use-effect

I'm trying to create a shopping cart, in 1 component the items are added to the shopping cart that places this data in the localstorage.

The shopping cart component looks like this, first with this code:

```
   useEffect(()=>{
  
        SaveToShoppingbag();
 
    },[])
```

SaveToShoppingBag() , looks like this:

```
let SaveToShoppingbag = () =>{

    if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Shoppingbag')) != null){
  
        SetShoppingbag(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Shoppingbag')))
       
    }
     
}
```

Based on that, the following useEffect is triggered:

```
   useEffect(()=>{
     SetTotalPrice(0)
       TotalPrices= []
       CalculatePrice()
     
    },[Shoppingbag])
```

Price calculations are correct. If a number of the product changes in the component, this is also neatly settled. Only when I add a product to the shopping cart from the other component (`localstorage.getItem('shoppingbag')` ) it is not added, which is probably due to the `,[]` in the useEffect. However, if I omit this, the price continues to count because it responds to a change in the shopping bag (`,[Shoppingbag]`)

So anyone have a solution? What if an item is added to the localstorage that the useEffect reacts to?

What I've already tried is to add an `eventlistner('storage')` but the browser doesn't respond to that because it probably has to do with SSR because I'm using NextJS.

Comment: You should probably consider using React context to manage the shopping cart across multiple components.